# How to click a button on a website through VBA?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to write a VBA code to get some info from a website to bring into excel. I am able to go to the website, click the login button, enter by login information, click the sign in button, but then I am stuck trying to close the 'Welcome Popup" on the main page. I should be able to close this welcome popup by writing code to either click the "continue" button or the "exit" button on the welcome popup. The Java code for each of these buttons will be posted below my VBA code. See my VBA code below:

Note: I am currently not getting any errors in excel from running this code, but it will not close the welcome popup.

```
Sub ASCElogin()

Dim objIE As Object
Dim UserName As String
Dim Password As String
UserName = Range("G7").Value
Password = Range("G8").Value

'Open Internet Explorer
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
.AddressBar = False
.StatusBar = False
.MenuBar = False
.Toolbar = 0
.Visible = True
.navigate "ASCE 7 Hazard Tool"

Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

End With

'Clicking Login Button then goes to 'sign in' page
For Each HTMLInputElement In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("waves-effect waves-light btn 
blue darken-3")
If HTMLInputElement.className = "waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3" Then
HTMLInputElement.Click

Exit For

End If

Next HTMLInputElement

Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

'Entering UserName
For Each HTMLInputElement In objIE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$main$LoginTextBox")
If HTMLInputElement.Name = "ctl00$main$LoginTextBox" Then
HTMLInputElement.Value = UserName

Exit For

End If

Next HTMLInputElement

'Entering Password
For Each HTMLInputElement In objIE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$main$PasswordTextBox")
If HTMLInputElement.Name = "ctl00$main$PasswordTextBox" Then
HTMLInputElement.Value = Password

Exit For

End If

Next HTMLInputElement

'Clicking Sign-In button and go to main page
For Each HTMLInputElement In objIE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$main$SubmitButton")
If HTMLInputElement.Name = "ctl00$main$SubmitButton" Then
HTMLInputElement.Click

Exit For

End If

Next HTMLInputElement

Do Until Not objIE.Busy And objIE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

'Closing Welcome Popup - this currently does not close the welcome popup - but I do not get any 
errors

For Each HTMLInputElement In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("details-popup-close-icon")
If HTMLInputElement.className = "details-popup-close-icon" Then
HTMLInputElement.Click

Exit For

End If

Next HTMLInputElement

End Sub

Java Code:

For the "Continue" button. Continue button is the last line of code below:

<div class="flex flex-column flex-justify-center align-items-center margin-vertical" data- 
reactid=".0.1.0.4.0.1.1">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3" data- 
    reactid=".0.1.0.4.0.1.1.0">Continue</a>

For the exit button in top right corner of the welcome popup. Exit button is last line of code 
below:

<div class="popup-header blue darken-3 welcome-header" data-reactid=".0.1.0.4.0.0">
    <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.4.0.0.0">ASCE 7 Hazard Tool</span>
    <span class="details-popup-close-icon" data-reactid=".0.1.0.4.0.0.1"></span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: check out the source of the page itself and the click handlers. some popups make shadow elements that are actually responsible for that close event, so clicking on that span isn't actually what's closing the dialog.

Comment: In the DOM is there any JavaScript functions that are part of the close button for the popup. Also, is the page fully loaded when the popup is attempted to be closed?

Comment: indexing in vba is with () rather than [] ^^

Comment: See if one of the parent element's classname needs a hidden class added. I can't see your post login page but with the guest page example I can use: ie.Document.querySelector(".details-popup-wrapper + .details-popup-wrapper").setattribute "class", "details-popup-wrapper hidden"

Comment: @nikki9696 I'm pretty new to coding, I'm not sure what you mean by "click handlers" or "shadow elements". How would I go about finding the shadow element for this popup box?

Comment: @tomBob I'm pretty new to coding and I'm not sure how to find java functions that are a pat of the close button. I posted the code for the close button. Is there code somewhere else that actually controls the close button?

Comment: @shadoe2020 dang I tried your suggestion but I cannot seem to get it to work. Yes, I believe the web page is loaded before running those last lines of code due to my "do while" & "loop" before it.

Comment: You'd have to inspect the page in the browser dev tools to find all attached click handlers and see elements that might not be visible in the DOM tree. There's nothing wrong with the code you posted from what I can tell, it's just that whatever is REALLY closing the button isn't that span.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @QHarr I tried your suggestion. It didn't work. Probably because I'm not sure how to implement the code you suggested correctly and the guest page you looked at is different from the page when you sign in. My sign in page has a welcome popup I cannot close out of and the guest page doesn't seem to have this popup.

Comment: I wondered if the principle was transferable. If you look at the class name you will see pop-up mentioned. It could be that you have a similar parent element who class name changes when you close manually the pop-up. You could arrange browser elements tab side by side with rendered page and look for this change.

Comment: If you know js you could use mutation observers otherwise, right click inspect the pop up to find a start area for inspecting and work up the DOM

Comment: @Nikki9696 Hmm. when I see the"continue" button I am clicking "inspect element". Are you saying theres a way to view the java code that shows hidden elements not shown when you inspect the element like i did? Again, sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm new to coding.

Comment: @qharr I inspected the DOM tree as best I could (with and without the welcome popup) I found another element with the same class name I used to click the close button. Could my issue be coming from there? Could I identify my close button from the "data-reactid"? if so, how do I denote that? Thanks!

Comment: Data-reactid is unreliable over time. Better to use a relationship between nodes or a different attribute

Comment: Do you mind showing my how to denote calling out an element by the data-reactid so I can try it? The close button only has a classname and data-reactid to identify it. I have tried ".document.getelementbydata-reactid("XXX") but VBA doesnt like the "-" in that line of code.